# Has any aircraft in history ever pulled 7g for 15 or more seconds?

Tags: aviation-history

According to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20230715091936/https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/fake-gripen-video/599765) "*no aircraft has ever pulled 7g for two seconds*"

If the interpretation of the video is correct, has any aircraft in history ever pulled 7g for fifteen seconds?

Comment: You quote some random person on the internet as fact... there are plenty of F-16 and F-18 pilots who would laugh at that statement & discuss routinely pulling, sustaining 7 or 8 or 9 G's for much longer than 2 seconds. Are you looking for those sorts of recollections to be documented? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, find one that said 15 seconds

Comment: Your question "Has any aircraft in history ever pulled 7g for two or more seconds?" is perfectly clear and simple to answer. No reason to close.  The rest of the text is based on a false assumption, frankly comes across as a bit unhinged, and I'm not even going to touch the link.  Don't need to... and you didn't ask anyone to verify it, although Chris seems to have done an excellent job debunking it.

Comment: Amusing that post: to uphold their theory that no aircraft can pull 7g they use a chart of an aircraft that can happily pull even 9g 

Comment: @sophit The strangest part to me is the completely unsupported jump from "this aircraft only pulled 4g" to "no aircraft has ever pulled 7g for two seconds."

Comment: .. and the Energy maneuverability chart in the link clearly show a small region with positive specific Energy (Ps) above and to the right of the 7 G line.  That clearly indicates that this aircraft can pull 7 Gs indefinitely, (or until it runs out of fuel anyway).

Answer (score 8):

Many aircraft are rated for 7Gs or more, and certainly many of them in history have pulled 7Gs for more than 2 seconds.  I know this to be a fact because I have personally experienced 7Gs for more than 2 seconds.

There is no problem with duration of time loaded at a certain G level.  For example, if an airplane is rated for 9Gs it can pull 7Gs for 2 seconds, 15 seconds, or several minutes.  The only real limit is fuel and pilot endurance.  (or pain threshold, 7Gs hurts...)

There are no time limits under load.  What ultimately leads to fatigue is the flexing caused by the number of cycles loading and unloading at various peak G loads.

Comment: As a non-pilot, I did the same on my F-16 incentive ride in Germany. In the prebrief, I asked my pilot...I want to see 9g on the meter. "OK, no problem". First attempt, 8.7. Second, 8.9, 3rd and last, 9.1 With me driving. Each was "more than 2 seconds".

Comment: @MichaelHall as you have noticed, the user that posted the original question keeps coming back with new accounts, as his original account has been suspended network-wide. His intensions are unclear to me, but he tries to solicit some kind of response. Please don't grace his behavior with any response, apart from flagging for moderator attention. As the saying goes: " don't feed the trolls".

Answer (score 4):

The "elementary math" in the post you've linked to is completely wrong. The formula they used is only valid if the aircraft is in a level turn with a constant radius of curvature (even then, it's ignoring the vertical component of lift required). But also it's wrong even *assuming* all that.

In the video, the aircraft goes from about point 4 in the picture to point 5 in the picture in about 3 seconds. Assuming it takes a circular arc, the path something like as shown:

[image]

Note: the points simply don't lie on any circle. With so few points, trying to extrapolate the actual ground track is mostly guesswork. Exactly what circular arc you end up with depends on what points you try to include in it.

This is a 60 degree arc, with a radius of about 940 meters, giving an arc length of 984 meters. Assuming the arc takes 3 seconds, this gives a groundspeed of 328 m/s. The acceleration is then $(328{~\rm m/s})^2/940{~\rm m}\approx115{~\rm m/s^2}\approx 11.7~\rm g$. Note that tightening the turn, as appears to happen based on this person's analysis, requires even more g's than staying in a constant-radius turn.

Almost 12 g's, that's crazy! Literally crazy. This is obviously incorrect. The reason for this is probably that the poster of the question also got the locations marked incorrectly, and the airplane was in a greater radius turn than these two points imply. The calculated number of g's is extremely sensitive to the *actual* ground track, and attempting to estimate it based off looks out the window is difficult at best. It's also quite sensitive to the time- I estimated 3 seconds based on watching the aircraft's shadow, but if it's 4 seconds instead you end up with a more reasonable $6.6~\rm g$. It's definitely *not* five seconds- the building they label as point 4 is almost directly out the pilot's front window at 1:18 and they are well past the trees by 1:23.

The direct error in their math is to blithely assume that 1 to "somewhere between 7 and 8" is 180 degrees. Plainly 1 to 6 is approximately 180 degrees, while 1 to 8 is around 227 degrees. Despite the unsupported assertion that "if we optimistically asusme it got to (8), thats still under 7g," using the same radius of 1000 meters and 15 seconds but with 227 degrees instead gives a little over 7g.

In short, this video's displayed g-forces plausibly agree with the aircraft's actual flight path. Since the aircraft goes considerably over 7g for considerably more than 2 seconds, the answer to your question is "yes." It is doubtless only one of many times this has been done.